# "No launchable target found" with newest VS Code + C# Dev Kit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Ever since "C# Dev Kit" came around, launch.json content changed to a simpler, yet (so far for me), completely useless content:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "C#: DbRefs Debug",
            "type": "dotnet",
            "request": "launch",
            "projectPath": "${workspaceFolder}/DbRefs.csproj"
        }

    ]
}
```

Apparently now we are meant to "launch" a project file instead of debugging by attaching to the compiled DLL, whatever this means.

Well, I would love to test-drive this new thing, except that it never works for me.  100% of the time, be it an existing project or a new Hello World project, I always get the error message "xxx.csproj does not support debugging.  No launchable target found.".

Any pointers?

Comment: I had the same problem since I've installed the "C# Dev Kit" extension. For other readers, the only solution I've found so far is to hit F1 and run the vscode command ".NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug". This command will generate the ".NET run" and ".NET attach" launch options for your project.

I have no idea why C# Dev Kit replaced the working "coreclr" launch config template with this new "dotnet" config that doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Worth noting that if you don't have a .sln or .csproj in your root the above comment errors out. Had to open VS code in the folder with my solution/project, trigger this, then copy the relevant files from the .vscode folder it creates to my project root, and modify the values to work.

Answer (score 6):

There is a comment that tells you to check out the config with IntelliSense

What you have to do Is to create a custom C# launch.json file

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<Target, like net6.0>/<YourProjectName>.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        },
    ],
}
```

And you configure the task in a tasks.json file also located in .vscode/

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/<Solution Name>.sln"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for stopping by.  So we went from a perfectly fine way of creating the debug configuration to what we have now, a useless construction where pretty much everything but one property needs revision?  I mean, your solution will produce a working configuration, but I cannot possibly believe that this "improvement" is meant to make us all go through this exercise over and over again.

Comment: So please correct me if I'm wrong, but I have provided a working and self explaining configuration, with all the possible properties. I have done that because so everyone can just take the properties that they want from my answer. Everything I have included in my answer is from the official vscode docs [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings). And also more than one property had to be added: program, task (and the whole task configuration) and cwd (optional for the solution explorer).

Comment: The question is why the configuration generated by VS Code + C# Dev Kit doesn't work.  Your answer is providing a way to make it work.  If you compare your configuration with what is generated, only one property matches.  Therefore your answer is read as "I don't know how to make this new configuration works, but here's one that does".  I think we can agree that the answer is not the answer to my question.  Furthermore, your configuration is what VS Code used to generate before the recent patches.  So your answer basically says "I don't know, just go back to previos configs".

Comment: Your question was answered. Your configuration is wrong, Î have updated and even switched to the pre lease version and everything works as it should be. And we have the possibility to "attach to the compiled DLL". So in this case I'm going to end this endless and pointless conversation because you say that my configuration is the old way creating this configuration. But how I already said I have my answer from the **official docs**: [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings). So in this case it isn't my problem if you can't accept the official docs.

Comment: It is not **my** configuration.  It merely is the configuration that VS Code + C# Dev Kit produces nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Projectpath should have double backslash instead of slashes

`"projectPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\DbRefs.csproj"`

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/950